# Delete files in subfolders, with option to keep one file in every folder

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have one root folder (Nowy3), with a lot of subfolders inside (1,2,3 etc.)
Every subfolder has a lot of files inside (Like Nowy3\1\file1.1, Nowy3\1\file2.1; Nowy3\1\file3.1).

I want make CMD script that save one newest file on every subfolder, and delete rest older files.
In single folder I can do that, but I cant do that when folder has subfolders and files inside this subfolders

I try this but it dont work

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %F in ('dir C:\Users\M\Desktop\Nowy3\* /b/o-d') do del C:\Users\M\Desktop\Nowy3\%F /S /Q
```

How change it ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because:

- you are ordering ***folders*** backwards by date and skipping the first.
  %F will contain the directory names, while you want files.

You need a two step approach,

1. iterating the folders, best with a `for /D`
2. iterate files (excluding possible subfolders) similar to your try

---

```
for /D %D in (C:\Users\M\Desktop\Nowy3\*) do @for /f "skip=1 delims=" %F in ('dir "%D\*" /b/o-d/A-D') do @echo del "%D\%F"
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `Echo` in front of `del`

Answer (score 0):

I try this code but it not finds any file

```
for /D %D in (C:\Users\MŻ\Desktop\Nowyfolder3\*) do @for /f "skip=1 delims=" %F in ('dir "%D\*" /b/o-d/A-D') do @echo del "%D\%F"
```

File Not Found
File Not Found
File Not Found
File Not Found

When i delete *, it shows files in **Nowyfolder3**, maybe i should use other method to list every subfolders, not *?

Ok, i found reason, subfolders has next subfolders so must be next option in code, but i try itself